# Distance between 2 decimal points

Tags: c++, gps, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a problem. How can I test in C++ if I have latitude and longitude of a point(a car with GPS) and I need to find if the point is inside the area of a circle. I have the center of the circle in latitude and longitude and the radius is in km.

For example:

I'm in the point :

52.51523649714909
13.18586926568004

And the circle center position is:

48.147763 11.563454
radius : 50km

I have this values from the project I need to resolve.

Comment: Refer to this page: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html